# class implementing UserDetailsService never called in login process

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i have a problem with spring security it redirects me to the login page even if i give the right credentials.
when i look to the server log i can't find any call to the class implementing UserDetailsService  here's the class used to validate credentials:

```
@Service
//@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private AdministrateurDao administrateurDAO;


    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String)
     */
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Administrateur domainUser= administrateurDAO.getUser(login);
        logger.info("loadUserByUsername username="+login);
        System.out.println("je suis dans customuserdetailsservice");
        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        //end de configuration de spring security
        return new User(
                domainUser.getLogin(), 
                domainUser.getPassword(), 
                enabled, 
                accountNonExpired, 
                credentialsNonExpired, 
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId())
        );

    }


    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
        return authList;
    }

    /*
     * i have two role admin and normaluser
     */
    public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
        //
        System.out.println("je suis dans role");
        //
        if (role.intValue() == 1) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
            roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
        } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
        }
        return roles;
    }


    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

for spring-security.xml :

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.nokia.controller, net.nokia.dao, net.nokia.service" />

    <beans:bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- spring security configuration -->
    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <!--<intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/alarmes" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/alarme/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rapports" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rapport/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/notifications" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/notification/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/administrateurs" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/administrateur/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

        <form-login login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/success-login"
            authentication-failure-url="/error-login" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <!-- end of spring security configration -->

    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="configLocation">
            <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="configurationClass">
            <beans:value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

and for my web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <!-- <welcome-file>list.html</welcome-file> -->
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlet and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!-- end spring container -->


    <!-- spring security filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- end spring security filters -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.eot</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.ttf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.woff2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

the login process always redirecting me to the controller that it's mapping the error-login path,so why customerusersdetails is never called even if it's recognized by spring because when i delete the implmentation  methods of UserDetailsService it gives me errors about implementing those methods coming from spring security.
i don't understand what's causing this problem,is there any way to debug my request, or can someone point me to the right direction.
thank u in advance.

Comment: If you are using struts where is your action result mapped to ?

Comment: annotate your service class with `@Service("customUserDetailsService")` and also confirm that bean is managed by spring context.

Comment: thank you for your replay i added @Service("customUserDetailsService") but still not working.for the mean i think it's managed by spring context because in spring-servlet.xml i got those lines <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.nokia.controller, net.nokia.dao, net.nokia.service" />
and those are the packages that spring context manage